# Receiving realtime updates for every single listview item

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `listview` which holds documents from `Firestore` and I want every `listitem` to receive realtime updates.

As this list is built from documents of different locations, I cannot simply listen to a collection. Instead I need to listen to every single `listview item` separately. This could end up in hundreds of simultaneous listeners, which would be really bad, as Firestore documentation suggests a maximum of 100 listeners per app instance.

As `listview.builder` constructs it's items on demand when scrolling into view and disposing items when scrolling out of view respectively, will this stop the corresponding listener? So that only the listeners are active which are currently in view.

Here is a code example:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: items[index].stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        // Snapshot prosessing
        return Widget;
      },
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't want that many listeners and streambuilders, maybe you just want one listener (lets call this Repository) exposing the updated value for the widgets?

You can expose a stream of items and build from it:

```
class DataRepository{

Stream<List<ItemModel>> get streamController.stream;

StreamController streamController = StreamController()
...

_initializeListener(){
    DocumentReference reference = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc("document");
        reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
            streamController.add(querySnapshot.toItemModelList());
    });
  }
```

You can listen to many documents at the same time

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

Do the filtering on the Firebase and you will have it easy